# How to fix the go build error "reflect.typedmemclr not defined"?

Tags: go, go-build

I was trying to build a go binary for centOS in a docker container, It's giving the following error:

`# command-line-arguments`

`github.com/ugorji/go/codec.rvSetDirect: relocation target reflect.typedmemclr not defined`

`github.com/ugorji/go/codec.rvSetDirectZero: relocation target reflect.typedmemclr not defined`

I tried `go build` with `-x` as well and don't see anything related to broken installation, still the build is unsuccessful with the above errors.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the  [`codec/helper_unsafe.go#rvSetDirect`](https://github.com/ugorji/go/blob/e6dffd531604d05d1eed9d467fd16794c0c9803c/codec/helper_unsafe.go#L511-L518) code, you have:

- a call to `typedmemclr(urv.typ, urv.ptr)`
- `func typedmemclr` defined in [`src/runtime/mbarrier.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/846dce9d05f19a1f53465e62a304dea21b99f910/src/runtime/mbarrier.go#L298)

So `import runtime` is missing in `helper_unsafe.go`

Comment: added the import, should I modify anywhere else? I've got the below error 
# github.com/ugorji/go/codec
src/github.com/ugorji/go/codec/helper_unsafe.go:15:2: imported and not used: "runtime"

Comment: @sbk OK it is another issue then, and you probably do not need that import. The function is defined as a linked function: https://github.com/ugorji/go/blob/e6dffd531604d05d1eed9d467fd16794c0c9803c/codec/helper_unsafe.go#L941-L943